# How to create a dictionary in Python from a csv considering the date and time values?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a csv file containing values of user's social media activity for 20 days I want to get the details of the user activity on Day 1
Here is the example of the entries in the csv

```
DateTime                  Instagram  Facebook   Twitter
(2020,09,01,10,00,00)        Y          N         Y
(2020,09,01,10,01,00)        N          Y         Y
(2020,09,01,10,02,00)        N          Y         N
(2020,09,01,10,03,00)        N          Y         N
(2020,09,01,10,04,00)        Y          N         Y
(2020,09,01,11,00,00)        Y          N         N
(2020,09,02,10,00,00)        N          Y         Y
(2020,09,02,10,00,00)        Y          N         N
(2020,09,02,10,00,00)        N          N         N
(2020,09,03,10,00,00)        Y          Y         Y
```

Here the `DateTime` column is a datetime object in the format(Year,Month,Date,Hour,Minute,Second) and as per the values even if one user is active on the social media app then it is considered as Y if none then N

I have created a dictionary named dict_1
where I want the output to look like this

```
{'Instagram':[Y,N,N,N,Y,Y],
 'Facebook':[N,Y,Y,Y,N,N],
 'Twitter':[Y,Y,N,N,Y,N]}
```

I have written a piece of code to calulate the number of rows until day 1

```
initial=dataset[DateTime[0]].date().day
final=inital+1
days_x=[]
i=0
while(initial<final):
    cons_date=dataset[DateTime[i]].date().day
    initial=cons_date.date().day
    days_x.append((cons_date.date().day,"-",cons_date.date().month," ",cons_date.time().hour,":",cons_date.time().minute))
    i+=1
```

Now I have written a piece of code to get an output like the one I have displayed above for the dictionary

```
dict_1={}
for i in range(1, len(dataset.columns)):
  if(dataset.columns[i] not in dict_1):
    dict_1[dataset.columns[i]]=[dataset[dataset.columns[i][:len(days_x)]]]
```

but then all the rows in the column get included in it and I get the output along with the index like this

```
{'Instagram':[0 Y
              1 N
              .....and so on
```

How do I get this fixed?

Comment: please show what the final dict should look like

Comment: @luigigi check the question I have edited it, the desired output section is highlighted the second highlighted block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `DateTime` column to pandas datetime format and grouped by date. Then create a dict for each day:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='(%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S)')

for idx, d in df.groupby(df['DateTime'].dt.date):
    print(d.drop('DateTime', axis=1).to_dict('list'))
    
{'Instagram': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'], 'Facebook': ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N'], 'Twitter': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N']}
{'Instagram': ['N', 'Y', 'N'], 'Facebook': ['Y', 'N', 'N'], 'Twitter': ['Y', 'N', 'N']}
{'Instagram': ['Y'], 'Facebook': ['Y'], 'Twitter': ['Y']}
```